# How can I style a form when it doesn't submit because of a required field or some other issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I mean when there is an error in the input in the form due to required or empty fields, how can I style the form in that instance.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyTzu.jpg)
Notice how the form labels and fields are red. How can I do that?

I tried using the form submit event to find out if there are no values in the field but nothing happens. Please help.

```
function func() {
    alert("nice!");
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
    var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
    var dayLab = document.getElementById("dayLab");
    var monLab = document.getElementById("monLab");
    var yrLab = document.getElementById("yrLab");

    if (day == null || month == null || year == null) {
        dayLab.style.color = "rgb(200, 0, 0)";
        monLab.style.color = "rgb(200, 0, 0)";
        yrLab.style.color = "rgb(200, 0, 0)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update (suggest a snippet) with the HTML and CSS you have in play here as a minimal example ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Apply the `required` attribute to appropriate inputs:

   `<input type="text" required>`
2. Add a listener on each input for the `invalid` event to add a class containing the styling you want.
3. (optional) If you want inputs to be validated as the user tabs through the form, add a listener on the form for the `focusout` event, to validate the field which just lost focus. The `checkValidity()` method automatically fires the `invalid` event if validation fails (which adds the class to style the input as invalid), but if validation succeeds you need to remove that class.

**Note** that if you submit a form programmatically using the `submit()` method, validation is not performed.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener("invalid", evt => {
    evt.target.classList.add('invalid')
  })
})

document.getElementById('f1').addEventListener('focusout', evt => {
  if (evt.target.checkValidity())
    evt.target.classList.remove('invalid')
})
```

```css
body, input {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input {
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=submit] {
  padding: 5px 12px;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
label:has(.invalid) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="f1">
  <label>First Name* <input type="text" required></label>
  <label>Last Name* <input type="text" required></label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make some styles when conditions are not met.

```
function func() {
    alert("nice!");

    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    const day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    const month = document.getElementById("month").value;
    const year = document.getElementById("year").value;
    const dayLab = document.getElementById("dayLab");
    const monLab = document.getElementById("monLab");
    const yrLab = document.getElementById("yrLab");

    if (!day || !month || !year) {
        dayLab.style.color = monLab.style.color = yrLab.style.color = "rgb(200, 0, 0)";
   
    } else {
   
        dayLab.style.color = "";
        monLab.style.color = "";
        yrLab.style.color = "";
        form.style.border = "";
        
        form.submit();
    }
}
```